# Not able to select proper time slot in calendar using xpath

Tags: selenium

I am using union to xpath and created one for day and time. Now, I am able to catch this path but when I used to click on that element using xpath, it's not getting proper time slot selected.

**My xpath is as follows:** `.//*[@id='calendar']//*[@class='fc-first fc-last']//*[contains(@class,'fc-wed fc-col3 ui-widget-content')]|.//*[@id='calendar']//*[@class='fc-agenda-slots']//*[contains(@class,'fc-slot3')]`

and need to use this xpath in for loop such way i can search each date and time slot till end of the calendar.

```
<table class="fc-agenda-days fc-border-separate" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
<thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="fc-first fc-last">
        <th class="fc-agenda-axis ui-widget-header fc-first"/>
        <td class="fc-sun fc-col0 fc-day-past">
        <td class="fc-mon fc-col1 ui-widget-content ui-state-highlight fc-today">
        <td class="fc-tue fc-col2 fc-day-past">
        <td class="fc-wed fc-col3 ui-widget-content">
        <td class="fc-thu fc-col4 fc-day-past">
        <td class="fc-fri fc-col5 ui-widget-content">
        <td class="fc-sat fc-col6 fc-day-past">
        <td class="fc-agenda-gutter ui-widget-content fc-last" style="display: table-cell; width: 17px;"/>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0px; width: 100%; top: 25px;">
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 189px;">
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;overflow:hidden">
<div style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0">
<table class="fc-agenda-slots" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="fc-slot0 ">
        <tr class="fc-slot1 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot2 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot3 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot4 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot5 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot6 ">
        <tr class="fc-slot7 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot8 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot9 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot10 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot11 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot12 ">
        <tr class="fc-slot13 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot14 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot15 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot16 fc-minor">
        <tr class="fc-slot17 fc-minor">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

above is my calendar code. This is my calendar image 
[image]

Comment: Yet another question when Xpath is too fragile to be usefull - seems we get few every week, yet people insist on using it (I avoid it if i can). And looking at the Xpath expression, i an NOT surprised it does not work consistently. OP: Try locating element by id, name or CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You want to accomplish your goal by having a very long xpath,

1. Xpath expression combines two xpath with a logical operator, make it hard to maintain
2. Xpath is less stable than css selector, make it hard to maintain

Please consider the following suggestions:

### using xpath:

```
listOfWeekdays = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='fc-first fc-last']/td")
```

- you can address Sunday ~ Sat by indexing `listOfWeekdays`, please bear in mind the very last element(`listOfWeekdays[7]`) in `listOfWeekdays` is NOT a week day; it is element `td[@class='fc-agenda-gutter ui-widget-content fc-last']`

`listOfWorkingHours = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='fc-agenda-slots']//tr")`

- you can address working hours 0~17 by indexing `listOfWorkingHours`.

### Using Css Selector:

listOfWeekdays = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[class='fc-first fc-last']>td")

- you can address Sunday ~ Sat by indexing `listOfWeekdays`, please bear in mind the very last element(`listOfWeekdays[7]`) in `listOfWeekdays` is NOT a week day; it is element `td[class='fc-agenda-gutter ui-widget-content fc-last']`

`listOfWorkingHours = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[@class='fc-agenda-slots']>tbody>tr")`

- you can address working hours 0~17 by indexing `listOfWorkingHours`.

### You may ask why xpath is less desirable than css selector?

- css selector is about identifying a web element by its attributes
- xpath is about identifying a web element by its attributes AND its whereabouts in HTML hierarchy tree. For a web element, its whereabouts in HTML hierarchy is prone to changes where attributes tend to stay the same.